# is there a way to use python-requests to access web pages which are in fact pdfs?

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests

I'm trying to use request to download the content of some web pages which are in fact PDFs.

I've tried the following code but the output that comes back is not properly decoded it seems:

```
link= 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf'
import requests
r = requests.get(link)
r.text
```

The output looks like below:
'%PDF-1.3\n%�쏢\n30 0 obj\n<>\nstream\nx��}ݓ%�m���\x15S�%NU���M&O7�㛔]ql�����+Kr�+ْ%���/~\x00��=����{feY�T�\x05��\r�\x00�/���q�8�8�\x7f�\x7f�~����\x1f�ܷ�O�z�7�7�o\x1f����7�\'�{��\x7f<~��\x1e?����C�%\ByLշK����!_b^0o\x083�K\x0b\x0b�\x05z�E�S���?�~ �]rb\x10C�y�>_r�\x10�<�K��<��!>��(�\x17���~�.m��]2\x11��
etc

I was hoping to get the html. I also tried with beautifulsoup but it does not decode it either.. I hope someone can help. Thank you, BR

Comment: What do you mean by "get the html"? PDF and HTML are two different formats. Do you want to extract the text from the PDF?

Comment: sorry, i'm trying to get an output like this: '<html dir="ltr" mozdisallowselectionprint=""><head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">\n    <title>

Comment: There is no such content at the URL you are making a request to. You should not expect to receive HTML, since no HTML is being sent.

Comment: using selenium i'm able to do it: driver.get(link)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# sleep(10)
html_source = driver.page_source
soup_source=bs(html_source,'html.parser')

font_spans = [ data for data in soup_source.select('span') if 'font-size' in str(data) ]
output = []
for i in font_spans:
    tup = ()
    fonts_size = re.search(r'(?is)(font-size:)(.*?)(px)',str(i.get('style'))).group(2)
    tup = (str(i.text).strip(),fonts_size.strip())
    output.append(tup)  --- this to get the font size for instance which is what i'm trying to get to

Comment: Selenium is a library which interacts with your browser. I suspect that Selenium is giving you the HTML that your browser uses to embed a PDF file in a browser tab. That HTML code is not sent by the server.

Comment: no it seems to give me what i want, i can even see some of the text that is in the pdf itself. The reason I can't use selenium is that this particular script does not seem to work in Google Colab.. whereas it works on my local instance..!

Comment: That means your browser is producing HTML that includes some of the text from the PDF, presumably so you can select it and copy it from within the browser tab. Nonetheless, that HTML is not the content of the PDF file, it is generated by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; a PDF file is a binary file, not a text file, so you should use `r.content` instead of `r.text` to access the binary data.

PDF files are not easy to deal with programmatically; but you might (for example) save it to a file:

```py
import requests

link = 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf'
r = requests.get(link)

with open('pdf.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: r.content seems to return stuff in that format: \xdd\x93%\xb7m\xef\xfb\xfc\x15S\xf7%NU\xf6\xb8 etc

Comment: Yes, binary data. If you want to view it, you will have to use a PDF viewing application, such as Adobe Acrobat, or SumatraPDF, or most browsers.